# Computes the average word length for all the words in a file?

Tags: python, file, average

So i need to write a program that computes the average word length for all the words in a file. So far i have this and am totally lost

```
newfile=input('Enter file name: ')
f=open(newfile,'r')
count1=0
count2=0
for line in f:
    count1+=1
    words=line.rstrip().split()
for word in words:
    count2+=1
average=count1/count2
print('Average words per line: ',average)
```

Comment: I might be wrong but it looks like what you're doing here is creating a ratio of words to lines in your input file. Did you want to do that, or did you want the average word length?

Comment: The only two things you need are the sum of the word lengths and the number of words. Don't overthink it.

Comment: 1. Get total length of all the words
2. Get total number of words
3. 1/2 -> will give you result

Comment: `totalWords = sum(1 for word in line.split() if word.isalpha())`

Comment: It is best to use variable names that help you understand the code.  Rather than `count1` and `count2`, I suggest `num_words` and `len_words` (short, easy-to-type abbreviations for "number of words in the file" and "total length of all the words in the file").  For a simple arithmetic mean (the most common average) you would then compute `len_words/num_words`.  In Python 2.x you should explicitly force at least one of these to a `float` first:  `float(len_words)/num_words`  but in Python 3.x that is not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

w<sub>i</sub> = length of word i

w<sub>avg</sub> = ∑ w<sub>i</sub> / N

```
with open(input('Enter file name: '),'r') as f:
    w = [len(word) for line in f for word in line.rstrip().split(" ")]
    w_avg = sum(w)/len(w)
```

Comment: one improvement: w_avg = float(sum(w))/float(len(w))

Comment: Nice solution bcorso, and nice addition @VladimirStazhilov.
I would also change line1 to include an encoding statement.
`with open(input('Enter file name: '),'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:`
Very minor - good job ppl.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you never actually calculate the length of a word. 
What you can do is to nest your for loops:

```
for line in f:
     for word in line.split():
```

And then increment the counters

```
       count1+=1
       count2+=len(word)   # len(word) gives you the length exactly
```

Finally, make sure you do float division (and not integer division) when counting the average:

```
average=float(count2)/float(count1)
```

I copy and explain your original code to let you understand what went wrong:

```
newfile=input('Enter file name: ')
f=open(newfile,'r')
count1=0
count2=0
for line in f:                             # here, line is a string containing many words
    count1+=1                       
    words=line.rstrip().split()            # here, "words" is a LIST of words
                                           # you exit your for loop here
                                           # so far, you looped over all your lines and did nothing with them
                                           # and in your "words" variable, only the last line will be stored


for word in words:                         # here, "word" is a word
    count2+=1                              # you increment the counter with one, not with the word's length
average=count1/count2                      # here, you perform integer division, and will lose the real part of the result
print('Average words per line: ',average)
```

Answer (score 0):

As for Python 2.7:

```
f = open('mercy.txt', 'r')

w = [len(word) for line in f for word in line.rstrip().split(" ")]
important to convert to float!
w_avg = float(sum(w))/float(len(w))

print 'Average word length: ', w_avg)
f.close()
```